# How to increment alphabetical characters without getting special characters after z?

Tags: python, character, ascii, increment

I have to create a program that gets a string, and an integer *n*; it will increment each character of the string by n characters; for example, if the string is "abc" and *n=1*, the output would be "bcd", if *n=2*, it'd be "cde".

So far I have written this code

```
string = list( input( "Insert a string, it will be codified: " ) )

n = int( input( "Insert an integer, each string's character will be increased by that number: " ) )

for characterIndex in range( len( string ) ):

    string[characterIndex] = chr( ord( string[characterIndex] ) + n )

print( ''.join( string ) )
```

Nonetheless, if I input "xyz" and *n=1*, I get "yz{", which makes sense since ascii's next character to "z" is "{". You can imagine that for a higher *n*, it gets worse; I have been trying to solve this problem for any *n* using modulo, tried to take advantage from the fact that there are 26 letters, but I'm still unable to find a mathematical increment that detects when the string has been incremented further than "z", so it "gets back" to "a".

Any recommendations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for modulo. eg: `(ord(a) - 97) % 25 + 1`

Comment: This worked, but I had to change the last 1 for a 97, and "a" in "ord(a)" for "string[characterIndex]". I clarify it in case anyone stumbles upon this same question.

Comment: I know it's probably ridiculous, but I never like approaches that map back and forth between characters and integers using ord() and chr(). In these days of near-universal ASCII, that's probably a ridiculous personal quirk; but I grew up on EBCDIC, where the letters do not contiguously map to integers, and some things are just hard to shake.

Comment: @codingatty Yes, especially with the dominance of UTF-8.  If you find it so offensive (or if you actually find yourself on an EBCDIC machine), then you can just add conversions to and from ASCII (or UTF-8).

Comment: Oh, not offensive at all. The most important thing is it works. Like I said, just ridiculous personal quirk on my part.I haven't touched EBCDIC in 30 years, but some things just run deep.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of cheating, but here's the approach I would take:

```
def string_bump(s):
    letter_list = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza" #note the extra 'a' at the end
    old_positions = []; new_positions = []
    for character in s:
        old_positions.append(letter_list.find(character))
    for pos in old_positions:
        new_positions.append(pos+1)
    new_string = ""
    for pos in new_positions:
        new_string += letter_list[pos]
    return new_string

for s in ["abc", "bcd", "xyz"]:
    print("before:", s, "after:", string_bump(s))
```

prints:

```
before: abc after: bcd
before: bcd after: cde
before: xyz after: yza
```

Basically, I scan the string to convert the characters to positions in the alphabet string; add 1 to each position; and rebuild the string from those positions. The "cheat" is adding an extra 'a' so a position-25 (counting from 0) 'z' translates to that extra position-26 'a'.

If that offends you, you could leave off the extra 'a' and instead just take another pass at the list of positions and when you see "26" (which would be past the end of the `letter_list` without the 'a'), knock it down to zero.

This is just a proof-of-concept for your example; to support an arbitrary shift, you'd extend the `letter_list` out for the full alphabet, and use modulo on the input (e.g. `n = n%26`) to ensure the input stayed in range.

Also, I would actually use list expressions in place of the `for` loops, but you may not have encountered those yet, so I used the more explicit `for` loops instead above.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complex to me (and it's a bit inefficient since it scans the "abcd...a" string for each character in the input string).

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down so that individual steps with named variables make it clear what you're dealing with:

```
asciiValue = ord(string[characterIndex])
alphabetIndex = asciiValue - ord('a')
alphabetIndex = (alphabetIndex + n) % 26
asciiValue = alphabetIndex + ord('a')
string[characterIndex] = chr(asciiValue)
```

Note that the above assumes that your input string is composed only of lowercase ASCII letters.  For uppercase characters, you'd need to subtract (and re-add) `ord('A')` instead.

Integrating it into your existing code:

```
def shift_letter(letter, n):
    asciiValue = ord(letter)
    alphabetIndex = asciiValue - ord('a')
    alphabetIndex = (alphabetIndex + n) % 26
    asciiValue = alphabetIndex + ord('a')
    return chr(asciiValue)

string = list( input( "Insert a string, it will be codified: " ) )

n = int( input( "Insert an integer, each string's character will be increased by that number: " ) )

for characterIndex in range( len( string ) ):
    string[characterIndex] = shift_letter(string[characterIndex], n)

print( ''.join( string ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought since we needed to encrypt only the alphabets I created a list of alphabets and looped them as below. This way when you input alphabets only alphabets shifted by the given number comes out even if the shift is large.

```
print("welcome to encryptor!!")
print("Do you want to encrypt or decrypt")
s = int(input("Press 1 for encrypt and 2 for decrypt: "))
alpha = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
print(alpha)

def encrypt():
string = list(input("Enter your string without space to encrypt: "))
print(string)
string1 = []
n = int(input("Enter the value key for caesar crypt: "))
for characterIndex in range(len(string)):
    for i in range(len(alpha)):
        if string[characterIndex] == alpha[i]:
            if((i + n)+1) >= 26:
                string1.append(alpha[(i+n) % 26])
            else:
                string1.append(alpha[i+n])
        else:
            continue
print(''.join(string1))
```

This code does produce the desired ouput..

Answer (score -1):

Here is the modified answer from the comments:

```
c = chr((ord(a) - 97) % 25 + 97)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing here: what is `a`?  Is this meant to be applied *after* adding `n`?  If not, where is `n` added?  And `% 25` is clearly wrong.